# SolrNet: How can I perform Fuzzy search in SolrNet?

Tags: solrnet, fuzzy-search

I am searching a "text" field in solr and I looking for a way to match (for e.g.) "anamal" with "animal". My schema for the "text" field looks like the following:

```
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt" />
            <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />

            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt" />
            <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Using SolrNet how can I perform a Fuzzy search to match "anamal" with "animal"?

Comment: Interesting! I've just run into the same issue trying to us the ~(tilde) in a field query. Looks like we might have to break out the debugger on SolrNet for this one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you can use the Lucene "~" fuzzy search, but there is a trick! If left unabated SolrNet will escape the tilde character for you by default, but it can be turned off... so this should do the trick for you:

```
var query = new SolrQueryByField("myField", "some value~");

query.Quoted = false;
```

The caveat seems to be that (for now at least) you have to use a query by field, the same parameter doesn't exist on a SolrQuery... but that makes sense I guess.

Comment: `SolrQuery` doesn't quote any special characters, so there's no need to set any flag...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with index time synonyms, please see the [Solr Wiki - SynonymFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory) for details on how to set this up.

Comment: oh, so I cannot do a fuzzy search using the tilde, "~", symbol in SolrNet?

Comment: Good question, I am not familiar with the tilde symbol and its behavior in Solr.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the tilde symbol use in Solr either. Thanks anyways.