# SolrNet Fuzzy Search More Than One Word

Tags: c#, lucene, solrnet, fuzzy-search

I am newbie on Solr and i want to full text search with SolrNet. So i used to MySql Full text search before and it is very slowly. I found Solr solution. This is very fast and scalability. But i can't fuzzy search in Solr. How can i do this? My examples and goals below. Excuse my badly english and thank you for advices.

I can fuzzy search but with one word (article):
For Example:

```
var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<Article>>();
List<Article> search = solr.Query(new SolrQuery("segsource:article~") ).Cast<Article>().ToList();
```

But i want to search more than a word (article name, bla bla bla - just like >

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body)
    -> AGAINST ('more than one word bla bla bla');
```

). 
For example

```
var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<Article>>();
List<Article> search = solr.Query(new SolrQuery("segsource:article name ~") ).Cast<Article>().ToList();
```

Comment: This is answered in this previously asked question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423498/solrnet-how-can-i-perform-fuzzy-search-in-solrnet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll see if there's a nicer way to do this, but in the meantime the following worked for me.

segsource:(article~ name~)

IE, you'd have to split the query on spaces and rejoin them inserting the tilda on each.

Answer (score 0):

I never used SolrNet, but would something like this produce anything relevant to you:

```
new SolrQuery("segsource:article~ AND segsource:name~")
```

Comment: Thank you for response. I want to search sentence or phrase and this solving does not conform to my goal. Because if i searched this way, i wouldn't search "article name~".